# Writing a program to display smallest and highest value - Not working

Tags: java, numbers

I am pretty new to Java and have been trying to write a program that takes 5 integers that the user has entered and then stores these integers in an array. Once this is done I wish to display both the smallest and the highest value that was entered.

Currently my code is able to display the highest value, but keeps on displaying 0 for the lowest value. If anyone is able to offer any advice on how I can fix this issue that would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class program {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int Numbers[] = new int[5];
    int lowest = Numbers[0];
    int highest = Numbers[0];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int c = 0; c < Numbers.length; c++){
        System.out.print("Please enter a number to enter: ");
        Numbers[c] = input.nextInt();
        if(Numbers[c] < lowest){
            lowest = Numbers[c];
        }
        if(Numbers[c] > highest){
            highest = Numbers[c];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The highest number is: " + highest);
    System.out.println("The lowest number is: " + lowest);

}
```

}

Comment: Currently you start with your lowest = to 0. You would have to add your values to your array before you do assign lowest or highest.

Comment: according to your code your variable `lowest` is always remain 0 no matter what value you enter my suggestion is first u take all 5 input from user and then find the lowest or highest

Comment: You could constants:
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class program {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numbers[] = new int[5];
    int lowest;
    int highest;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int c = 0; c < numbers.length; c++){
        System.out.print("Please enter a number to enter: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        if (c == 0) {
            lowest = number;
            highest = number;
        } else {
            if(number < lowest) {
                lowest = number;
            }
            if(number > highest){
                highest = number;
            }
        }

        numbers[c] = number;
    }

    System.out.println("The highest number is: " + highest);
    System.out.println("The lowest number is: " + lowest);

}
```

Also, why do you keed all the values? The program doesn't use them.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are initializing it with 0

```
int lowest = Numbers[0];
```

and all the values you are entering as input are greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have with the lowest number is because it has been initialized as 0 in the array. I suggest instead to initialize both number as

```
int numbers[] = new int[5];
int lowest = 0;
int highest = 0;
```

And keep the rest of your code as it is.